# How do I combine, one-by-one, two lists of names?

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation

I have two lists of names that are the same length and I'd simply like to combine them into a third list so the first value in each list is combined, then the second, and so forth.  I know I'm missing something very obvious.

I've tried using "+" but that doesn't work for the two lists.

```
mgr_name = pd_ex.iloc[3,:].tolist()

prod_name = pd_ex.iloc[4,:].tolist()
```

I would like the output to be: [mgr_name 1 + " " + prod_name 1, mgr_name 2 + " " + prod_name 2, ...]

Comment: can you provide some sample data and what is your expected output????

Answer (score 3):

This will yield the list you seek:

```
[x[0]+' '+x[1] for x in zip(prod_name,mgr_name)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mgr_name = pd_ex.iloc[3,:].tolist()
prod_name = pd_ex.iloc[4,:].tolist()
third_name = [mgr_name[i] + ' ' + prod_name[i] for i in range(0, len(mgr_name))]
```